# regexp word boundary for strings enclosed in non alnum chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I have looked at various posts at on the subject but cannot find a satisfactory answer

I need a regexp to match a string like #xxx# - that is a string which may have characters in the front and back that are not in a-z A-Z 0-9 - where it is within word boundaries - that is preceded and followed by ^ or $ or a char that is not in a-z A-Z 0-9

I am looking to use this with replace with case insensitive and global matches, I am looking for a solution in the form of:

regexp for #xxx#:

```
'#xxx#'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => 'bla'
'#xxx#,#xXx#)'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => 'bla,bla)'
'(#xXx#, #xxx#)'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => '(bla, bla)'
```

and:

```
'a#xxx#'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => 'a#xxx#'
'#xXx#0'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => '#xXx#0'
'hello'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => 'hello'
```

regexp for xxx:

```
'xxx'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => 'bla'
'xxx,xXx)'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => 'bla,bla)'
'(xXx, xxx),'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => '(bla, bla)'
```

and:

```
'axxx'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => 'axxx'
'xXx0'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => 'xXx0'
'hello'.replace(regexp, 'bla') => 'hello'
```

etc

I tried various solutions (ie `(?!\w)#xxx#(?!\w)`) but cannot get it to work.

Basically I'm looking for \b that works when the string has non alnum chars around.

Any help ?

Comment: Can you give some testing cases of match and not match?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: Is there a list of what characters might be considered part of the "word"? Your only examples are that `'#'` and `','` *are* part of the word, but parentheses are not. I find it a little strange that you are not treating commas as word boundaries, but anyway...maybe you can match on `[^ ().-;:)]+[a-z][^ ().-;:)]+`, i.e., list all of the characters that you consider to be word boundaries as characters to *not* match.

Comment: any char outside of a-zA-Z0-9 in the *searched string* is a boundary char, but *all* chars of the *string we are looking for* are used regardless of what they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure a regexp solution is possible, I went with a javascript solution like this:

```js
const isAlnumChar = c => (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');

const replace = (s, f, r) => {
  const lcs = s.toLowerCase(), lcf = f.toLowerCase(), flen = f.length;
  let res = '', pos = 0, next = lcs.indexOf(lcf, pos);
  if (next === -1) return s;

  do {
    if ((next === 0 || !isAlnumChar(s[next - 1])) && (next + flen === s.length || !isAlnumChar(s[next + flen]))) {
      res += s.substring(pos, next) + r;
    } else {
      res += s.substring(pos, next + flen);
    }
    pos = next + flen;
  } while ((next = lcs.indexOf(lcf, pos)) !== -1);
  return res + s.substring(pos);
};


console.log(replace('#xxx#', '#xxx#', 'bla'));
console.log(replace('#xxx#,#xXx#)', '#xxx#', 'bla'));
console.log(replace('(#xXx#, #xxx#)', '#xxx#', 'bla'));

console.log(replace('a#xxx#', '#xxx#', 'bla'));
console.log(replace('#xXx#0', '#xxx#', 'bla'));
console.log(replace('hello', '#xxx#', 'bla'));

console.log(replace('xxx', 'xxx', 'bla'));
console.log(replace('xxx,xXx)', 'xxx', 'bla'));
console.log(replace('(xXx, xxx),', 'xxx', 'bla'));

console.log(replace('axxx', 'xxx', 'bla'));
console.log(replace('xXx0', 'xxx', 'bla'));
console.log(replace('hello', 'xxx', 'bla'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but to restrict the pattern as

> preceded and followed by ^ or $ or a char that is not in a-z A-Z 0-9

You can use `/(^|[^0-9a-zA-Z])pattern goes here([^0-9a-zA-Z]|$)/`:

- `(^|[^0-9a-zA-Z])` will match the beginning of string or a char that is not in 0-9a-zA-Z;
- Similary `([^0-9a-zA-Z]|$)` matches the end of string or a char that is not in 0-9a-zA-Z;

*Testing cases*:

1) for *#xxx#*:

```js
var samples = ['#xxx#',
               '#xxx#)',
               '(#xxx#,',
               'a#xxx#',
               '#xxx#0',
               'hello']
               
console.log(
  samples.map(s => s.replace(/(^|[^0-9a-zA-Z])#xxx#([^0-9a-zA-Z]|$)/, '$1bla$2'))
)
```

2) for *xxx*:

```js
var samples = ['xxx',
               'xxx)',
               '(xxx,',
               'axxx',
               'xxx0', 
               'hello']
              
console.log(
  samples.map(s => s.replace(/(^|[^0-9a-zA-Z])xxx([^0-9a-zA-Z]|$)/, '$1bla$2'))
)
```

Comment: thx ! this solution does not work for me, it also selects the punctuation to the sides (ie selects the ')' in #xxx#) which is explicitly what I don't want as I use it in replace.

Comment: If you want to extract the pattern, you need to capture it. try `s.match(/(?:^|[^0-9a-zA-Z])(#xxx#)(?:[^0-9a-zA-Z]|$))` or see the update.

Comment: I don't follow - can't this be done within the regexp itself ? the (?:[^0-9a-zA-Z]|$) is a nono capturing group, why is it included in the result ?

Comment: It depends on what functions you use. With `match` for instance, if there's no capture group in the pattern, it will return the original string if there is a match, so match a string and extract a pattern is not the same thing.

Comment: I want to do s.replace(regexp, 'bla') - edited my question to make it clear

Comment: It will make the regex more complicated. Is there any reason you specifically want to use `replace`?

Comment: yes in my case I am doing string replaces inside css strings

Comment: sorry for the confusion :( edited my answer to make it clear

Comment: I see. If you need to replace a matched pattern with something else instead of extracting it. then `replace` is the right choice.

Comment: You are asking an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That's why we have so many back and forth. But hopefully it works this time.

Comment: ok this is very close. But you're right I am figuring the question as I go and apologies. The last thing I need is for this to work with the 'g' flag ... so to work with ie, (#xxx#,#xxx#) ... editing the question now